# Bluetooth share application crashes when I call startLeScan()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm working in bluetooth low energy application. Whenever the device gets disconnected from the application. I'll scan periodically in certain interval of time in the background. (using Service component) Sometimes in Nexus and Samsung devices I'm getting the following exception.

```
04-29 14:32:04.141: D/BluetoothAdapter(969): startLeScan(): null
04-29 14:32:04.151: E/BluetoothAdapter(969): android.os.DeadObjectException
04-29 14:32:04.151: E/BluetoothAdapter(969): at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
```

Due to this issue, automatically the default bluetooth share application switch gets disabled.Unable to switch on. To back to normal condition I need to restart the device.

Comment: Excuse me , do you solve this problem ? I have the same error log...`E/BluetoothGatt( 3667): android.os.DeadObjectException`

Comment: @Wun This issue is in default android OS. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67272)